# Logic error in pygame code designed to change colour of list of circles blitted on screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have this small piece of code using `pygame` that is meant to generate a set number of "snowflakes" on the screen and to turn each one of them from white to yellow before each one reaches the end of the screen and is reset.

The program generates a list of 40 snowflakes and assigns each one an x,y and colour variable (that consists of an R, G and B value).

The problem is that when i -0.1 to the specific R, G or B value for each snowflake, it effects every single element in the list, not just the specific snowflake `i`.

Therefore the colour of each snowflake is in sync with the rest, when actually i want it to be unique to each snowflake element.

What am i doing wrong and how can i resolve this?

The full code can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/bobshaniqua/180d94108cd5ade97e6c3e50b504c9e7).

```
    import pygame, sys, random, time #import modules
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

BLACK = (0,0,0)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snow Animation")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Animation():
    def __init__(self):
        self.snow_list = [] #create snow list (list of circles to blit across screen)
        self.R = 200 #RGB values for each snow 
        self.G = 200
        self.B = 200
        self.colour  = [self.R,self.G,self.B] #combines values together in list
        for i in range(20): #Creates 40 snow items, 20 from x axis, 20 from y axis
            self.x1 = random.randint(-1000, 0)
            self.y1 = random.randint(0, 600)
            self.snow_list.append([self.x1, self.y1, self.colour]) #2D list. Gives each snow element an x,y value and assigns the colour variable
            self.x2 = random.randint(0, 800)
            self.y2 = random.randint(-1000, 0)
            self.snow_list.append([self.x2, self.y2, self.colour])



    def snow(self):
        for i in range(len(self.snow_list)):
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, (self.snow_list[i][2]), (self.snow_list[i][0],self.snow_list[i][1]), 5) #draw circles
            # Move the snow flake down and across one pixel 
            self.snow_list[i][1] += 1 
            self.snow_list[i][0] += 1
            self.snow_list[i][2][2] = self.snow_list[i][2][2] - 0.1 #-0.1 to self.G in self.colour variable for each snow_list element
            # If the snow flake has moved off the bottom of the screen
            if self.snow_list[i][1] > 600:
                # Reset it just above the top
                self.snow_list[i][2][2] = 200 #reset colour variable for each snow element
                self.new_pos1 = random.randint(-50, -10)#gives it new random position at these coordinates before y=0 axis
                self.snow_list[i][1] = self.new_pos1
                self.y_change = random.randint(0, 800) #sets random variable along y axis
                self.snow_list[i][0] = self.y_change
                # Give it a new x position
            if self.snow_list[i][0] > 800: #does same as the 6 lines above but for the x axis snow flakes
                self.snow_list[i][2][2] = 200
                self.new_pos2 = random.randint(-50, -10)
                self.snow_list[i][0] = self.new_pos2
                self.x_change = random.randint(0, 600)
                self.snow_list[i][1] = self.x_change
                print (self.snow_list[i][2][2])




        pygame.display.flip() #update display
        clock.tick(30) #clock tick

Snowing = Animation() #create class instance
while True:
    screen.fill(BLACK) #fill screen black before snowflakes are blit
    Snowing.snow() #run snow module
    for event in pygame.event.get():   # User does something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  #if user quits
            pygame.quit(), sys.exit() #quit
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue lies at line `54`.

If I understand correctly, you want each snowflake to update it's color independently. Therefore, you should update the display *within* the for loop.

Line `54`should be indented once so that the color is updated with every iteration of the for-loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix the issue. The colour is still changing for all snow_list elements in the list. The only difference is the display looks slightly more glitchy; the circles on the display flash really fast essentially.